# Title for deleted question is not parsed from the link

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, title

When the URL of a regular (not deleted) question is entered in a post, e.g.:

```
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/630268
```

It will be parsed, and the final post will contain the title, able to read by humans. Here it is:

> [Исключить дублирование кода в функциях с разной константностью](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/630268)

But for deleted question such parsing doesn't work. E.g.:

```
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/605493
```

Ends up with:

> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/605493

By contrast, if I open a link to a deleted question in the browser's private mode (even after deleting a title from link, i.e. only with question id), the title slug is generated and I can see a correct title:

> [image: 404]

I think this inconsistency should be fixed and links to deleted questions should be parsed the same as links to regular ones.

Comment: The title slug on the link **on the post (not the address bar)** is irrelevant. I guess this report can be simplified to: *why link to deleted post is not converted into its title, even if the title can be seen on the address bar as title slug?*

Comment: I have rewritten this post, and removed the point about the title slugs in the link, as well as hopefully improved some of the phrasing and organization. I found the original post difficult to interpret. I hope it is clearer. If not, I apologize, and feel free to roll back, or improve.

Comment: @JasonC thanks for edit. It looks much better now.

Comment: The issue still persists on  2021-01-14

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly intended behaviour. Deleted questions are deleted to prevent people from accessing their content, and that includes the title. Being able to access the title by simply using the link in another post would defeat the purpose of deleting that post.

Comment: Title is still accessible if you follow the link for deleted question as showed in the picture.

Comment: @alexolut: The fact that the URL slug is regenerated even if you don't have enough rep to view the question itself probably *is* a bug. Probably not a serious bug, since typically having a link to the question means that you already know the slug, too, but a bug nonetheless.